# laravel the best way to check the contents of a variable

Tags: laravel

I have a few questions, the first one is:
What is the best way to check if the variable has any records from the database. e.g when I want get single row from collection:

```
 $variable->sth->first()->url
```

I get reply:

> Call to a member function first() on null.

So if I will use something like this:

```
@if($variable->sth->count() > 0) 
   code here 
@endif
```

is this correct ? and what's the difference between 
`@if($variable->sth->count() > 0)` and `@if(count($variable->sth)>0 @endif` because both work, but not always

second question is: Why when I want get one row from collection and when collection is empty an error appears? but when I use foreach to get all rows from db and when collection whether row is empty, nothing is not appears.

the third question is: when should I check that, the returned data isn't empty?

I'am newbie, sorry.

Comment: Please improve the code formatting. Also, try to not group questions into a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to check if the variable has any records from the database.

You can use laravel methods like [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-dd) or use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see the content of a variable.

> I get reply: Call to a member function first() on null.

That happens because property `sth` in `$variable` is null so it doesn't contains a function or member called `first()`

> Why when I want get one row from collection and when collection is empty an error appears? but when I use foreach to get all rows from db and when collection whether row is empty, nothing is not appears.

Foreach evaluates first if there is data on the collection before doing whatever. You are getting an error because you are accessing a row that **maybe** doesn't exist. You need to evaluate first if the collection is null or not before accessing its data

> when should I check that, the returned data isn't empty?

Before attempting to use it